# Can software development benefit from mindfulness?

Tags: vipassana, meditation, mindfulness, meditation-daily-activities

Can software development benefit from mindfulness?
As I'm software developer and as I want to register for Vipassana meditation so far I couldn't because of time but still thinking if I could go for it.
Today I found that meditation and eventually mindfulness can be beneficial for my profession or others. Even I was thinking that my focus will improved and I could study hard and well.
Though it's titled software I think it's beneficial for other fields too.
So let me share if software development benefit from mindfulness?

Comment: See related question: [*"Being mindful sitting/working on a computer"*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/being-mindful-sitting-working-on-a-computer).

Comment: @Lanka When he found restlessness doesn't mean he isn't calm also sensation because of conscious with what he doing actually. He distracted from track. So he need to pay more focus to his work. Suminda answered well. So if mind would wander then not possible to do any work. Not only while sitting on computer but wherever we do work and that's why my opinion is for all other jobs and not limited for computer related. Thank you.

Comment: @Lanka Welcome @-}-- My pleasure to share Dhamma.

Comment: Yes, such mindfulness has brought you tools like the wikiwikiweb.  Go visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SD Times explains that in [Converging software development and mindfulness](http://sdtimes.com/converging-software-development-mindfulness/) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> Software development requires ***concentration and focus***, an understanding of designing, coding, languages, and programming and how they all work together. It can also require comprehension of technology, science, engineering, and math. Clearly, a lot of brainpower goes into being a software developer.
>
> In order to keep that ***brainpower in a positive flow, it’s important to train mental clarity***, the science and techniques behind the mind to avoid stress; *this can all be done through* **mindfulness**.
>
> *Mindfulness* promotes your **emotional intelligence (EI)** – *strengthening mental resiliency, building a clearer mind, and embracing a happier inner self – all helping to create a brighter outlook.*  ***Enhancing all of these emotional traits*** and ***raising your self-happiness*** translates to better confidence, improved communication skills, and greater interpersonal relationships.
>
> However practicing mindfulness is not the goal itself, but rather a means to reach your goals.
>   ***Numerous studies have shown that changing one’s inner landscape (values, emotions, thoughts) through brain fitness can free the mind of anxiety, pressure, and negativity. Remove this mental clutter and replace it with greater EI and you’re left with enhanced creativity, greater aptitude for thinking, and a better ability to stay within the present and task at hand.*** For a software developer, having a clear, balanced and focused mind can be a tremendous asset while striving to produce high-quality software and aiming to balance work with life.
>
> Hopefully you see how **mindfulness**, if it becomes part of your life routine, can help you become a more efficient software developer. But where do you begin? [etc.]

So my personal opinion is that I'd say it not even beneficial for only software development but also all of professions and when people seeking how to deal in their business or which field they want to choose(with aware of precepts) for example a question [A Good Career for a Buddhist](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/a-good-career-for-a-buddhist)?
So with only awareness of precepts one can choose any job and ***Mindfulness*** can be more beneficial to achieve one's goal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every profession gains from mindfulness, even the butcher — the butcher will eventually abandon his profession, if he perseveres in his mindfulness, and stays true and honest to himself. A software engineer has more to gain from mindfulness than the butcher or the hunter, as he will only deepen the love for his special skill.

Personally, being a self-taught software engineer and weirdo, I have some visions which I have been working on. Some time ago already I started noticing that whenever the visions, which are sometimes extremely clear albeit partial, become muddy or foggy or I get distracted by excitement, I need to switch over to blockages in personal or family life, or go help a friend with something important. When I have spent some time and effort doing that, the visions soon reappear and become clear again so I regain my confidence and are able to continue working on extending and solidifying them once again.

I used to almost panick when, after such “recovery”, they would continue to get blurred again over and over. By now however, I have almost fully accepted this pattern. I am left knowing that whenever it reoccurs, it is a reminder of some defilement that hasn’t been resolved.

Mindfulness on its own is useless, it has to serve the ultimate purpose of restoring orderliness of the mind space, so that we gain our natural superpowers. Because IT is such a mind-space oriented field, it should be obvious that mindfulness is critical in IT. Would you enjoy working with an engineer who lacks clarity of mind?

After all, the binary system was borrowed from Taoism and yin-yang, and Taoism is definitely quite close to Buddhism when it comes to mindfulness and wisdom and diligence.

Answer (score 0):

Benefit for what? In what way, Nyom Swapnil? To keep many from practicing **right mindfullness** for a real benefical way, or to make software more desireable for benefit in the world. Software and IT has so much success on the marked, because it gives people the illusion that they can control things so that they will propably never see anicca and lose many, many factors on right view, wordily and beyound. Just look at gratitude, respect... click, click, click...

Mindfullness and concentration, the path structur in and of it self, is fundamental base for any development. If one follows that, he will have success in any work, but for what benefit, what aim.

One is sure, the EightfoldPath, that gift and generosity was not meant, shouldnot be misused for low aims likewordily gains, althought it is all what the Dhamma is used for in most cases: success in things which are not benefical, for low gains and to pull people into the world.

But if one realizes, while getting cracy while programming, this is suffering, that is the cause, that the cessation of the cause and this is the right path to cessation of delusion, yes in that case, having right mindfulness and proper attention, it can be of great benefit. So when suffering arises with it, and the path is known and understood, and if real benefit is known: Yes it can.

So far, IT in this dimension, had not really helped many since it's appearing and if it would be a real support, the Buddha would had written the final code.

So it's importand to know that Dhamma is not given for one's goal, but "just" one's noble goal.

It's good and not wrong, to use the skills also for the maintaining for ones live of noble benefit, but it's unwise to misuse a generous gift to use it for ones greed.

And it's good to be mindfull and know: this intent is for Nibbana and this for the world. The world becomes hoter and hoter if mindfulness is wrong used, not to sprak about bound.

Note also that the IT-world has by far not even the moral and ethic of the notmal world and bussiness and is place of thieving No. One. People living in the IT world seldom having much base for the first training section of the path and really less of them would even investigate their mind because not trained in the basics and mostly not guided by good teacher, taking just where and what they want. Gratitude got lost, good language got lost, respect got lost, moderation got lost... IT did not brought any global benefit at least and the amount of conflicts and skill in war has increased: it's originated to win over others, it did not come into existence out of compassion for one self and others, yet it could and does make the streets where people used to live, more silent and the marked full of beings.

Normal and humble people react like when sitting in cars: in delusion they have now all under their controll become the ugliest people in just a secound.

(*Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant to be used for commercial use or other wordily gains.*)

Comment: Johnan I already mentioned that with awareness of **precepts**. And benefit is successful career or business as if we living mundane life and in this modern world. We can be happy ourself with mindfulness. I honestly tried to put efforts and nothing else. Thank you.

Comment: It's good to have a work that does not require wrong doing. It's geat if putting an effort to be mindful and heedfull to keep precepts also in every job, it's possible to lead a great householderlive with Nyoms work, and my person trusts, that he is1 allwaly most eager in his good effort. May Nyom stay in good assosiation wise and alway seek wise and makes his Vipassana retreat soon, put it most high in all what Nyom can do for himself and Dhamma, but Fhamma on the top, make merits, visit Monks, look after livelihood in tune.

Comment: Nyom @Swapnil , Seek after all of the [highest Blessing/Protections](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/piyadassi/protection_en.html#s2), ([here book with explaining](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=item33) as raga/saddha-charita , ([here good book for householder](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=item134) to explain), stay with the wise, better seek after wise. And [Livelihood](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index_en.html). Abhivādana-sīlissa
 Niccaṃ vuḍḍhāpacāyino
Cattāro dhammā vaḍḍhanti
 Āyu vaṇṇo sukhaṃ, balaṃ.

Comment: Johnan Thanks for source and I'm agree with you but when I think of Buddhism or even techniques and knowledge I felt it's all about life and want to use for our life to be happy, successful, peaceful and not greedy. Buddhism for well being. I understand what you have to tell and I tried to help. Thanks a lot.